# Extending average calculation over set of rows

Tags: mysql, window

I have a table with following columns:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | bigint(20)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id       | mediumint(9)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_stamp       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_date       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shamsi_date      | varchar(12)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_final      | decimal(10,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| natural_sell_no  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| natural_sell_vol | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| natural_buy_no   | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| natural_buy_vol  | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_sell_no    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_sell_vol   | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_buy_no     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_buy_vol    | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Some Data:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id | company_id | time_stamp          | shamsi_date | legal_final | natural_sell_no |
+----+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 |          1 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    10499.00 |             232 |
|  2 |          2 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    13876.00 |             156 |
|  3 |          3 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     5147.00 |             491 |
|  4 |          4 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     7050.00 |             586 |
|  5 |          5 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     4282.00 |             831 |
|  6 |          5 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     4282.00 |               0 |
|  7 |          6 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    55386.00 |             297 |
|  8 |          7 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    50713.00 |             115 |
|  9 |          8 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     6151.00 |             224 |
| 10 |          9 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    25397.00 |             266 |
| 11 |         10 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    15007.00 |             623 |
| 12 |         11 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    17779.00 |             233 |
| 13 |         14 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    13044.00 |             225 |
| 14 |         15 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    12216.00 |               3 |
| 15 |         16 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    68967.00 |              61 |
| 16 |         19 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    16974.00 |             124 |
| 17 |         21 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     7665.00 |             333 |
| 18 |         22 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     8444.00 |             259 |
| 19 |         23 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    11427.00 |             171 |
| 20 |         26 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     3872.00 |             130 |
| 21 |         27 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     3452.00 |             488 |
| 22 |         28 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    20752.00 |              71 |
| 23 |         29 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     5503.00 |             503 |
| 24 |         30 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     8638.00 |             184 |
| 25 |         31 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    23162.00 |             178 |
| 26 |         33 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    41389.00 |             111 |
| 27 |         34 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    43090.00 |             148 |
| 28 |         35 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    19552.00 |             287 |
| 29 |         36 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |    17761.00 |             255 |
| 30 |         37 | 2019-11-29 20:08:05 | 13980609    |     7550.00 |               6 |
+----+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I use the following query to calculate an average over the last distinct 30 rows of a company_id ordered by shamsi_date:

```
select company_id, avg(c.natural_buy_vol + c.legal_buy_vol) from 
(
 select company_id, natural_buy_vol, legal_buy_vol 
 from legal_daily
 where company_id = 1
 group by shamsi_date 
 order by shamsi_date desc
 limit 30
) as c;
```

The output is:

```
1   1523659.9667
```

which is technically true.

My question is: How can I perform such calculation over all company_ids? i.e. desired output will be:

```
1   1523659.9667
2   <some average>
3   <some other average>
..  .....
```

MySQL version is:

```
Server version:         8.0.14 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Comment: You are looking for conditional aggregation,

Comment: Just to be clear 'last distinct 30 rows of a company_id ordered by shamsi_date:' could mean that the date ranges included in the analysis for companies might differ and if all the rows are for the same date then that is fine.

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually one row for each company should be persisted daily. [There exist about 600 companies] But some companies do not have data in special days, and unfortunately the API gives more than one data per day for some other companies.  So data is not completely clean.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an avg for fixed  set of rows you could use a row_number and group by the integer diviion for you rowset range

```
  SET @your_range = 10;
  SET @row_number = 0; 
  select  num div @your_range  my_range , avg(natural_buy_vol + legal_buy_vol)
  from (

      select (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
        , company_id, c.natural_buy_vol,  c.legal_buy_vol 
      from     (
         select company_id, natural_buy_vol, legal_buy_vol 
         from legal_daily
         where company_id = 1
         group by shamsi_date 
         order by shamsi_date desc
      )  c
  ) t 
  group by  my_range
```